# Can't Install Django Packages in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I just deployed my app to Heroku and I am getting an error when opening the application, it says: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'" and the same for MultiSelectField.

I have tried to install these packages in the console at the platform, but it seems to have no effect, every time I run 'heroku run pip freeze' I get the same packages.

I have tried to do this in my local console running the following commands:

```
heroku run bash
pip install django-crispy-forms
pip install django-multiselectfield
pip freeze # To check if the packages where installed
```

Then I get that everything seems fine, django-crispy-forms and django-multiselectfield appear in the packages list in the 'pip freeze' command, but when I check in the platform, the updates are not there.

As suggested below, I added the "requirements.txt" file in the root folder, with the Pipfile, Procfile.

The "requirements.txt" file was added with the code pip freeze > requirements.txt:

```
argon2-cffi==18.1.0
bcrypt==3.1.4
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==2.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
-e git://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra- 
views.git@aa58167af84d89feea286f9567a72cc5941360e4#egg=django_extra_views
django-heroku==0.1.0
django-multiselectfield==0.1.8
django-session-timeout==0.0.3
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.7
mailsnake==1.6.4
numpy==1.14.5
pandas==0.23.3
Pillow==5.2.0
pipenv==2018.5.18
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pycparser==2.18
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2017.3
requests==2.19.1
six==1.11.0
stripe==2.4.0
urllib3==1.23
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

My Pipfile is the following:

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true


[packages]

django = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
django-heroku = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
django-multiselectfield = "*"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

The output of my git push heroku master is the following:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 711 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:        Skipping installation, as Pipfile.lock hasn't changed since 
last 
deploy.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 156.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v14
remote:        https://blooming-headland-56472.herokuapp.com/ deployed to 
Herok
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/blooming-headland-56472.git
   d4535c9..5966fd9  master -> master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

The changes you make through `heroku run bash` are not sustained. Once you quit the bash the dyno is immediately terminated.

I suggest you create a requirements.txt like `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the root folder or mention dependencies in Pipfile.

> *Dependencies specified in Pipfile or requirements.txt are automatically installed when you deploy your application.*

Add this in your Pipfile

```
[packages]
django-crispy-forms = "*"
django = "*"
django-multiselectfield = "*"
```

Comment: I have tried that but with no success, the problem in the platform remains the same.

Comment: Have you committed and pushed this new Pipfile?

Comment: When you push to deploy like `git push heroku master` post the output. It's probably something like : `Counting objects: 1999, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (616/616), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1999/1999), 461.28 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1999 (delta 1139), reused 1983 (delta 1131)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.12
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt                <===========
remote: -----> Launching...
remote: Verifying deploy.... done`

Comment: I added the output in the description of the problem.

Comment: Try `pipenv lock` 
Then `git add Pipfile Pipfile.lock` , commit and push

Comment: The error has changed, now it is saying: ModuleNotFoundError: No module name                    d 'django_session_timeout'

Comment: django-session-timeout should be added to Pipfile then.  If its still not working post your middlewares.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and install packages manually. You should create a requirements.txt file and commit it to git, then Heroku will automatically install the packages on deploy.

The reason what you have done does not work is that `heroku run bash` - or any command - creates a completely new dyno; you install the packages there, but the dyno is immediately killed when you quit and other dynos are not affected.

Comment: I just made the requirements.txt file and added the following code:

dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==2.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-heroku==0.1.0
django-multiselectfield==0.1.8
gunicorn==19.7.1
pipenv==2018.5.18
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pytz==2017.3
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
whitenoise==3.3.1

It still does not work with me.

Comment: Did you add this file to the root of your repository?

Comment: Yes, the same location as the Procfile, Pipfile, and so on. I have tried also the pip freeze > requirements.txt code, but nothing seems to work.